# Java: Jlist setSelectedValue() but ignoreCase

Tags: java, swing, case-sensitive, jlist

```
myJList.setSelectedValue("someTHING", true); //if "SomeThing" in the list, it won't be selected
```

I want to set the value, but seems like setSelectedValue is case-sensitive, I want to select a value but ignore case-sensitive, is it possible? and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding `String` objects to your `ListModel` you could write your own `String` wrapper and override the `equals(Object o)` method to be case insensitive. This might have implications for other areas of your app.

Answer (score 1):

I [can't see](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) any one shot method for that but merging one or two method you can have this.

call [`getNextMatch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getNextMatch) until you find the exact element and then `setSelectedValue`

Answer (score 1):

setSelectedValue()  is not case sensitive, Java is case sensitive.
Two solutions:

1. Use all upper or lower case in your List
2. When selecting the value loop through the list and compare the value to the String you want to select using the equalsIgnoreCase() method of String.